# Issues submitting firemonkey app to app store

Tags: iphone, ios, delphi, app-store, firemonkey

I have tried dozens of configuration settings trying to get this to work, but still to no avail...

When I am trying to submit to the app store, the application loader is reporting the following error

> iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required
>   architecture. At least one of the following architecture(s) must be
>   present: armv7.

My understanding is that fpc 2.4 can only generate armv6 code anyway.

I have tried setting all build settings to only reference armv6, installed the previous version of XCode 3.2.6 and linked with the iOS SDK 4.3, hoping that this will address any references to armv7, but still no joy.

According to the XE2 Update 4 release notes, fpc 2.6 supports armv7, but despite the release notes having been available for weeks, there is no sign of the update!

Has anyone successfully uploaded an app using current tools (it surely has to be possible), and if so, could you please share your secret!

Thank you

Comment: Let us know once it's in the app store, and how to find it. I think most delphi developers with an ipad or iphone would be very interested to see what you did.

Comment: For anyone who is interested, I have finally submitted the app after spending another day fighting the code signing which did not want to behave.  I tried dozens of the solutions recommended on the 200,000+ google references to this problem.  Finally in desperation I uninstalled xcode, then reinstalled.  That fixed it.  Delphi XE2 Firemonkey/iOS environment is very buggy, but it is beginning to look quite good now I have been using xcode for a while!

Comment: Thank you to all who have followed this post, FYI the app has now been approved and is available at http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=505367719&mt=8

NB: It only available in Australia, New Zealand and a couple of other countries at the moment, so not sure if the link will work for you if you are elsewhere.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have upgraded to FPC 2.6 and all is okay.

I was reluctant to do this as it would make my development environment 'non-standard', however it was quite painless.

There is a paragraph in the release notes to the effect that nothing has changed in the xcode environment.  This is probably accurate to an extent, but it is at least a little misleading as the compiler now builds armv7 code okay which is the issue I needed resolved.

Comment: No need to apologise. Good question and you have the solution which could very well be useful to others. +1 x2